# While using trial mode of live CD, if I install drivers, will it affect my main system?

Tags: drivers, lubuntu, live-usb

(Background info)

I have Ubuntu 12.04 on my HP 110 netbook and it's working perfectly and configured as I like it.  I have to use the 2d desktop though because it's not a powerful system. Since Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't have the 2d desktop, I am experimenting with Lubuntu 14.04

(Question)

When I am running Lubuntu 14.04 in "try Lubuntu without installing it" from a live USB, can I install wifi drivers without messing with my installed Ubuntu OS in any way?  I don't want to risk it if there is a chance of messing up my beloved Ubuntu 12.04 installation.

Comment: nope it won't!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you boot any Ubuntu derivate in live mode, it stays in live mode as long as you don't mount any partitions from your disk into the file system. All data will be stored in a RAM disk. You can safely (lets say 99%) change everything you want, it will be gone by the next reboot.